# Dismissing a modal view controller via code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

iPhone project/iOS 7.1/objective-C  Due to circumstances, i have presented a navigation controller which contains a view controller which in turn   contains a web view.All of the before said are added programmatically  (i.e. no .h,.m or xib files).How do i dismiss the navigation controller?

P.S: I've created all these in a method.There is no property or instance available for the navigationcontroller.

Comment: Can you show us what you've got?

Comment: if you navigate with navigationController you will have a navigationController on pushed controller too. You can call [self.navigationController popViewController] in pushed view controller.

Comment: `UINavigationController` instance is always available with `UIViewController`, you can directly use it by `self.navigationController`

Answer (score 4):

you have to create on `barButtonItem` on navigation bar like "Back" or "Done" and on it's click event you should write :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The view controller from where i am pushing the navigation controller does not have a navigation bar since it is hidden i.e. i've hidden it. Again there is no .h or .m file ,so there is no way to add a action method with self dismiss view controller and since it is added programmatically there is no way to add delegate method to the push view controller. So, how could i control the view controller on the screen without the .h,.m files?

Comment: This works for an action extension as well, thanks so much man